# angularjs auth admin module one single layout or more?

Tags: angularjs

Usually you've got an app
needs user authentication + admin module.
I don't trust manage all my app with a single page
and I don't like to have the hassle to manage
the auth with angular 
so I usually divide my app in three

- admin
- default
- login

What's do you thing about it ?

Answer (score 2):

I use two apps Home and Panel:

1. **Home**: website, contact us, usual stuffs and login, single-page app on /# .
2. **Panel**: for the admin panel, single-page app in /panel# so that I can check session on the backend, any template needed by Panel is protected by auth filter also any backend API call. It's a good approach to use csrf checks too.

Comment: Are you using one or two layout ? my approach for the front-end / for the admin /admin you enter in admin by the /login (an other layout) so I've got three single app easy to manage imo. I use both csrf and JSON vulnerability protection take a look at https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/created_by/whisher?labels=&state=open

Comment: As I said I'm using two apps with multiple templates for each. ex: /#signup, /#contact, /panel#billing /panel/#settings